# Edittext in Android Alert

Tags: android, android-edittext, alert, show

I am trying to show an alert with two edittext fields in Android. The source is as follows:

```
public void UserPass(){
    final SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("PrefsPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String user=prefs.getString("user", "");
    String pass=prefs.getString("password", "");

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("U/P");
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    final EditText input1 = new EditText(this);
    final EditText input2 = new EditText(this);
    builder.setView(input1);
    builder.setView(input2);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //My code
        }
    })

    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Only one EditText is showing up. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Ondra,use separate  layout for `AlertDialog` with two `Editbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `setView` call replaces the `EditText` you set in the first. You can't add two `View`s this way. Instead, create a `LinearLayout`, add both `input1` and `input2` to that, and then add that to the `builder`.

Answer (score 5):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DialogWithInputBox extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    alert.show();

}
```

}